# Auto Build Marlin extension showing random board and environment?

Tags: marlin, firmware

I am trying to compile firmware for an Ender 5 Plus with its stock 8-bit board with ATmega2560. The environment is set correctly and it compiles the hex file as it should when I use PlatformIO:Build (and runs fine when I can actually get it to upload).

I want to try Marlin AutoBuild to try uploading via their utility. However, as you can see it populated with some random board for a printer that is not hooked up and not specified in platform.ini

Where are these fields being populated from?

Again, the firmware folder that is loaded currently is for the Ender 5 Plus and I have not had any others loaded recently that used the BTT board.

[image: Screenshot of the Marlin Firmware Auto Build environment in VS Code]

```
[platformio]
src_dir     = Marlin
boards_dir   = buildroot/share/PlatformIO/boards
default_envs = E5P_BIL
```

```
[env:E5P_BIL]
platform      = atmelavr
extends       = common_avr8
board         = megaatmega2560
build_flags = ${common.build_flags} -DMachineEnder5Plus -DHotendAllMetal - DBedDC
```

Comment: Hello, benram14159. Please don't upload images of text, code, or errors. They are not searchable and are inaccessible for the visually impaired using a screen reader. Please [edit] your post to include actual text. (For more info, please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors))

Comment: @agarza thanks for the advice. I will follow whenever possible. Unfortunately that window in VSCode does not let me select any of the text to copy/paste it here.

Comment: In a situation like the VS Code window, it is understandable to have an image of that. But simple text, code, or errors should be actual text. Thank you for understanding.